# Python Pandas Column Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

Below is an example of a pandas database:

```
     player  games  result
855    Zoom    156       0
856    Zoom    213       1
857  Zothve      7       0
858  Zothve      2       1
859      zs     55       0
860      zs     20       1
861   Zvene     34       0
862   Zvene     25       1
863  Zz1tai     54       0
864  Zz1tai     60       1
```

I have another dataframe with players and their win rates

```
       player  winPercentage
0        Zoom        71.6049
1          zs        71.4286
2       Zvene        71.2025
3      zz1tai        70.3704
4  DREAMPYLLA        69.8113
5        Khan        69.2857
6      Looper        68.4932
7      Buggax        67.2269
8       Mouse        67.1053
9        Apii        66.6667
```

As you can see, each player has 2 columns associated with their name based on the result, where a 1 is a win and a 0 is a loss. I am trying to take the win percentage for the player from table B and put it in a new column on table A. I've tried a couple permutations including what is below and I haven't found a solution that works.

```
for name in a['player']:
    wp = b['winPercentage'].loc[b['player']==name].to_string(index=False)
    try:
        if zip(a['player'], a['result']) == (name, 1):
            a['WinPercentage'] = float(wp)
        else:
            a['WinPercentage'] = 1-float(wp)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I know if it was all numeric I could use numpy and I know I'm not supposed to iterate down the pandas rows. I know that a lambda function is an option but I haven't been able to get one to work. I'm looking for advice in not only a way to make this work but also the most pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just trying to join the two dataframes based on the player column. So :

```
df = df0.merge(df1, on="player")
```

Where `df0` and `df1` are the first and second dataframes you described, respectively.

Comment: I'm guessing I can't just do df = df0.merge(df1['winPercentage'], on="player") to just get the 1 column moved over.

Comment: You can easily drop the columns you don't want from your final dataframe with df[["player", "other_col", "yet_another_col"]]. This will select only that list of columns that you want to keep.

Comment: Is it possible to just use something like df0 = pd.merge(df0, df1[['winPercentage']], on='player', how='left' )? The only issue I have here is I think one of the players in df0 is not in df1 and so it's throwing an exception.

Comment: No, because then you'd be merging with a dataframe that doesn't even have the player column needed to merge.

Comment: I'm checking this comment as it was the best solution with the data available to you. I realize I left some information out. My final solution was to create 2 dataframes off the main ones, merge them as you showed, and then apply a lambda function to one of them. I'll post the solution in a second comment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `dft = df_wl[['player', 'games','result']]
tat = df_ta[['player','winPercentage']]
dft2 = dft.merge(tat, on='player')

def func(result, winPercentage):
    if result == 0:
        return 100-winPercentage
    else:
        return winPercentage

dft2['winPercentage'] = dft2.apply(lambda x: func(x['result'], x['winPercentage']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

Merge the two dataframes, then search for where result = 0, and change to np.nan.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on="player", how='left')
df['winPercentage'] = np.where(df['result']==0, np.nan, df['winPercentage'])

   player  games  result  winPercentage
0    Zoom    156       0            NaN
1    Zoom    213       1         71.605
2  Zothve      7       0            NaN
3  Zothve      2       1            NaN
4      zs     55       0            NaN
5      zs     20       1         71.429
6   Zvene     34       0            NaN
7   Zvene     25       1         71.203
8  Zz1tai     54       0            NaN
9  Zz1tai     60       1            NaN
```

Comment: If A and B have a bunch of other columns in them. Is there a way to either only merge the winPercentage column into A?

Comment: df1[['player', 'games', 'result']].merge(df2[['player', 'winPercentage']], on="player", how='left')  --- only columns in the brackets will be merged; all others will be ignored. as noted in comments below, you need 'player' specified in both dataframes